# AutoCompleteTextView is taking much time to search in huge Sqlite database

Tags: android, performance, sqlite, autocompletetextview, custom-adapter

I have my own dictionary application WordYard and in that whenever we type in AutoCompleteTextView i am showing the words list in dropdown.

In addTextChangedListener of autoCompleteTextView i am querying for written text in sqlite database. Since database is very huge of 1.5 lac words it takes time to make the arraylist of particular text.

Suppose I wrote 'A' then this string will searched in database and written inside arraylist of limit 15 data starting from 'A'. On scrolling the dropdown list i am adding next 15 words in getView of adapter.

Scrolling is fine but whenever i type in autocompleteTextview to read 15 words from database also it take time if we write faster. Please tell me if there is any other method i can do it to make my app better.

Comment: Post your code if it's possible.

Comment: you don't need any addTextChangedListener/TextWatcher at all, see my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19860624/2252830

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everytime you type anything within `AutoCompleteTextView` a query to your relative huge database is sent thus causing the (justified) delay.

The `addTextChangedListener (TextWatcher watcher);` method needs a `TextWatcher` object to operate. What your are going to to is create a `TextWatcher` and override it's `afterTextChanged (Editable s)` method in order to perform queries to your database less often.You will also need a custom `Filter` for that.

```
autoCompleteTextView.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
   public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
      yourAdapter.getFilter().filter(s);
   }
```

then you will create a class that extends `[Filter][1]` and override the methods suitable to your needs.

For example optimize your implementation to send queries only after 4 characters are typed or some time has passed.

Comment: Thanks, is it possible to that you write an example code for custom Filter